# Accepting comments and reviews constructively

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

When we do a review and mark an answer as URL only, stackoverflow pastes a message as comment. So the author hits back at reviewer in an unfair manner. Is there a way to stop it?

Comment: I feel its more upto the user and there is not much which can be done here. Its a good feature and I doubt if it should be stopped. Just for an example, have a look at one of the [auto generated comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049364/how-to-add-multiple-item-buy-from-paypal-new-sdk/20346634#comment30371717_20346634) posted when I marked an answer as *link-only* and how the OP responded to it.

Comment: FYI: In VLQ reviews the delete comment is optional. The canned comments are just there to improve your reviewing flow. If a comment is not required (e.g. other reviewers have already commented on whatever is wrong with the answer), you can recommend delete with "No comment needed".

Comment: @laalto If there is already a comment from the review queue then selecting that option wouldn't add another comment anyway; it would just upvote the existing comment.

Comment: @Servy Ah, good to know. Back in the day when I was learning VLQ review mechanics the canned comments would just get appended, resulting in unnecessary noise.

Comment: Beyond some harsh words (which can get that user banned if he/she does it often), there's not a whole lot that user can do - [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you aren't prepared to defend your actions as a reviewer when the post's author responds with either further requests for clarification or (constructive) arguments as to why your statements don't apply, then you shouldn't be reviewing the posts.  Not attaching a name to the review action comments would only encourage users to make review decisions that they are capable of defending, which is an action that they shouldn't have taken in the first place.

If the users respond in an unconstructive, insulting, offensive, or otherwise inappropriate manor, simply flag the comments and do not respond further.  A mod will be able to resolve the situation for you.

Comment: its more on bashing from the auto generated comments..

Comment: I don’t agree with all of my site’s policies, but I try to follow and support them, anyway. Are you suggesting that I should enforce only those policies with which I agree?

Comment: @Scott I'm saying that if you are going to take an action, such as closing/editing/deleting a question, and someone asks you why you did it, or why that action is the site policy, you should be able to respond.  That may mean explaining what the site policy is, why it was added, or simply linking to the help center or canonical meta post on the subject.  If someone asks why you voted to delete their post for being VLQ and your response is, "I don't know" then you probably shouldn't have suggested deletion of that post.

Answer (score 8):

The way you deal with any other undesirable comment:

1. Refrain from engaging in an extended off-topic discussion about it, and
2. Flag the comment if it is particularly unsavory.

This is especially true of system-generated comments.  These are blessed by the powers that be, so the only quarrel that a person being reviewed might have is in the review decision, not in the message itself.